# What is Win32/Process.pm in @INC?

Tags: visual-studio, build, win32-process, activeperl, opendds

Setup

- OpenDDS -3.14
- Windows 10 64bit
- Active Perl 5.8
- VisualStudio 2019

I am trying to build OpenDDS and try out the messenger example as given in the [instructions](https://opendds.org/quickstart/GettingStartedWindows.html). The **configure** commanded executed, but I got the following error. What is this error and how to solve it?

```
Can't locate Win32/Process.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Win32::Process module) (@INC contains: E:\opndds_\OpenDDS-3.14\ACE_wrappers/bin E:\opndds_\OpenDDS-3.14/bin C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib) at E:\opndds_\OpenDDS-3.14\ACE_wrappers/bin/PerlACE/Process_Win32.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at E:\opndds_\OpenDDS-3.14\ACE_wrappers/bin/PerlACE/Process_Win32.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at E:\opndds_\OpenDDS-3.14\ACE_wrappers/bin/PerlACE/Process.pm line 63.
Compilation failed in require at E:\opndds_\OpenDDS-3.14\ACE_wrappers/bin/PerlACE/Run_Test.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at E:\opndds_\OpenDDS-3.14\ACE_wrappers/bin/PerlACE/Run_Test.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at E:\opndds_\OpenDDS-3.14/bin/PerlDDS/Run_Test.pm line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at E:\opndds_\OpenDDS-3.14/bin/PerlDDS/Run_Test.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at run_test.pl line 13.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at run_test.pl line 13.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install [the missing dependency](https://code.activestate.com/ppm/Win32-Process-Info/). Alternatively you could try [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).